# Simplify an equation where a fox chases a rabbit

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on the following question and don't know how the book got its answer because it has multiple variables (its precalc so I don't know how to do calculus yet) and I don't know how to eliminate one completely.  Any help is much appreciated.

**Question:**
Suppose Fritzy the Fox, positioned at a point $(x,y)$ in the first quadrant, spots Chewbacca the Bunny at $(0,0)$.
Chewbacca begins to run along a fence (the positive $y$-axis) towards his warren.
Fritzy, of course, takes chase and constantly adjusts his direction so that he is always running directly at Chewbacca.  If Chewbacca's speed is $v_1$ and Fritzy's speed is $v_2$, the path Fritzy will take to intercept Chewbacca, provided $v_2$ is directly proportional to, but not equal to $v_1$ is modelled by:
$$
y
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^{1+v_1/v_2}}{1+v_1/v_2}-\frac{x^{1-v_1/v_2}}{1-v_1/v_2}\right) + \frac{v_1v_2}{v_2^2-v_1^2}
$$

a.) Determine the path that Fritzy will take if he runs exactly twice as fast as Chewbacca; that is $v_2$ = $2v_1$.  Use your calculator to graph this path for $x \ge 0$.  What is the significance of the y-intercept of the graph?

So in order to graph this with the provisions of a (where $v_2$ = $2v_1$) I believe I need to reduce this function down to one variable.  So here is my attempt:
$$
y
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^{3v_1/2v_1}}{3v_1/2v_1}-\frac{x^{v_1/2v_1}}{v_1/2v_1}\right) + \frac{3v_1}{v_1^2}
$$
$$
y
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^{3v_1/2v_1} - 3x^{v_1/2v_1}}{3v_1/2v_1}\right) + \frac{3v_1}{v_1^2}
$$
From here I believe I can get rid of the $v_1$ in the first term because it is present in both numerators and denominators.  So here goes:
$$
y
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^{3/2} - 3x^{1/2}}{3/2}\right) + \frac{3v_1}{v_1^2}.
$$
But I don't know how you get rid of the $v_1$ in the second term because it is squared in the denominator.

I maybe even be on the completely wrong path as the book answer is:
$$
y
= \frac{1}{3} x^{3/2} - \sqrt{x} + \frac{2}{3}.
$$

Can anyone help me understand what I have to do to get the book answer?

Comment: Please use a more specific title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct apart from the last fraction
$$v_1v_2=v_1(2v_1)=2v_1^2$$
$$v_2^2-v_1^2=(2v_1)^2-v_1^2=4v_1^2-v_1^2=3v_1^2$$
So
$$\frac{v_1v_2}{v_2^2-v_1^2}=\frac{2v_1^2}{3v_1^2}=\frac23$$
also your answer simplifies becuase
$$\frac12\left(\frac{x^\frac32-3x^\frac12}{3/2}\right)=\frac{x^\frac32-3x^\frac12}{3}=\frac13x^\frac32-x^\frac12=\frac13x^\frac32-\sqrt{x}$$

Comment: Thank you Peter!